# Refactoring is operator at base method

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have some interfaces `ISome1, ISome2 .. ISomeX`
I have classes that could be inherited from some of these interfaces

```
      class SomeModel1 : ISome1 , ISome2
      {
         // specific properties
      }

       class SomeModel2 : ISome3 , ISome12
       {
         // specific properties
       }
       class SomeModelX : ISomeXX , ISomeXXX
       {
         // specific properties
       }
```

I have a class that do some action based on that interfaces has an object

```
 public void InitSomeModelProperty(SomeModel model)
 {
    if (model is ISome1)
    {
        var isomeAcation = new SomeAcation();
        isomeAcation.InitProps(model);    
    }

    if (model is ISome2)
    {
        var isomeAcation2 = new SomeAcation2();
        isomeAcation2.InitProps(model);    
    }

    // it is a dozen of logic like this
    if (model is ISomeX)
    {
        var isomeAcationX = new SomeAcationX();
        isomeAcationX.InitProps(model);    
    }
 }
```

how to correct reduce the amount *if (model is ISome1)* ?

Comment: If you have some name conventions you could use reflection... but its dirty, bypassing your strong typing.

Comment: What is `SomeModel` here? Is it a base-class of all your models? I suppose you shouldn't have a single method that handles different things. If you instead create a method per interface-type there's no need for any switch.

Comment: Why you have dozend of interfaces which mean nearly the same? This cries for refactoring(maybe generics), but with just pseudo code and no background information it's impossible to help.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to move the knowledge of what types an action can handle into the action itself. E.g.:

```
public abstract class ActionBase
{
    public abstract void Handle(SomeModel model);
}

public abstract class ActionBase<T> : ActionBase
{
    public override void Handle(SomeModel model)
    {
        if (model is T typedModel)
        {
            InitProps(typedModel);
        }
    }

    protected abstract void InitProps(T model);
}

public class SomeAction1 : ActionBase<ISome1>
{
    public override void InitProps(ISome1 model) { ... }
}
```

Then:

```
public void InitSomeModelProperty(SomeModel model)
{
    someAction1.Handle(model);
    someAction2.Handle(model);
    ...
}
```

`InitSomeModelProperty` then doesn't need knowledge of which actions take which types -- that knowledge is held by the action itself. `InitSomeModelProperty` just needs to iterate through all of the possible actions: I've written this out explicitly, but you could put them all in a collection, for example (which is why I introduced the non-generic `ActionBase`).

If you need to have a new action *instance* for each model, then you'll probably want a factory for each action, and the factory decides whether to instantiate its corresponding action for a given model.